# Nestjs returns 401 (Unauthorized) even with valid user ft. passport-local

Tags: nestjs, passport.js, passport-local

Hi awesome developers,

I'm trying to implement Authentication using passport-local and Nestjs with reference to https://progressivecoder.com/how-to-implement-nestjs-passport-authentication-using-local-strategy/.

I have implemented exactly same but Nestjs always returns 401 Unauthorized even with valid user. I can't seem to find what I am missing.

**Code Structure**

[Authentication Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emejV.png)
[User Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K2Ux.png)

**Here's the code:**

***Authentication Module:***

*authentication.module.ts*

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { AuthenticationController } from './controllers/authentication.controller';
import { AuthenticationService } from './services/authentication.service';
import { LocalStrategy } from './strategies/local.strategy';

@Module({
  imports:[UserModule, PassportModule],
  controllers: [AuthenticationController],
  providers: [AuthenticationService, LocalStrategy]
})
export class AuthenticationModule {}
```

*authentication.controller.ts*

```
import { Controller, Post, Request, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { UserService } from 'src/user/services/user.service';

@Controller('authentication')
export class AuthenticationController {

    constructor(private userService: UserService){}

    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
    @Post('signin')
    async signin(@Request() req){
        return req.user;
    }
}
```

*authentication.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from 'src/user/services/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
    
    async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.userService.readUserByEmail(email);

        if (user && user.password === password) {
            const { password, ...result } = user;
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

*local.strategy.ts*

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../services/authentication.service";

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy){

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){
        super();
    }
    
    async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.authenticationService.validateUser(username, password);

        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

***User Module:***

*user.module.ts*

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserController } from './controllers/user.controller';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

*user.controller.ts*

```
Skipping user controller as it is irrelevent
```

*user.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { prisma } from 'src/main';
import { CreateUserDTO } from '../dto/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDTO } from '../dto/update-user.dto';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    private readonly users = [
        {
            id: "1",
            name: "Ajitesh",
            email: "ajitesh@example.com",
            password: "secret"
        }
    ]

    //....other methods

    async readUserByEmail(email: string){
        return this.users.find(user => user.email === email);
    }
}
```

*Request:*

```
{
 "email": "ajitesh@example.com",
 "password": "secret"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also share what your request looks like?

Comment: EDIT: Added request. 

Guess, passport expects username and password but I am passing email and password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`passport-local` expects `req.body` to be populated with `username` and `password` fields. If you plan to use something else for the username, like `email`, then you need to tell passport about that in your strategy using the `usernameField` option in `super`

```js
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../services/authentication.service";

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy){

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){
        super({
            usernameField: 'email',
        });
    }
    
    async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.authenticationService.validateUser(username, password);

        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, it worked! Guess I was wondering how to tell passport-local to use email instead of username.