# NestJS Local Auth Guard always returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: nestjs, passport.js, http-status-code-401, guard, auth-guard

I'm having a problem, which from what I've searched is kinda normal to happen. I'm trying to use the local auth guard and the local strategy from NestJS, still without the JWT part, and I'm always getting the 401 Unauthorized. My code is very similar with the documentation code from the NestJS docs, here's my local.strategy.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return user;
  }
```

Here's the validateUser from my auth.service.ts:

```
async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOneWithEmail(email);

    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (user && isPasswordValid) {
      const { ...result } = user;
      return result;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Now my findOneWithEmail function from users.service.ts:

```
async findOneWithEmail(email: string) {
    return await this.userModel.findOne({
      email: email,
    });
  }
```

Note that, ultimately I want to use a DTO instead of the email and password in the validate functions, but I've tried with the DTO and it was not working, then switched it up to email and password, as it is in the docs. Also note that I have all my imports, exports and providers as it is in docs, so I think that might not be the problem.

If you need and more relevant info, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

I expect it to return the Passport user, I think, instead I'm just getting the 401 constantly.

Comment: What are you sending as the request?

Comment: I'm sending an email and a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and solved it. It was an easy solution. I found it here: [Nestjs returns 401 (Unauthorized) even with valid user ft. passport-local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74017615/nestjs-returns-401-unauthorized-even-with-valid-user-ft-passport-local)

Looks like if you want to send your own param in the validate you have to include it in super(), passport expects a username and a password.

Answer (score 0):

I need more info to help you.
you should first check is user returning expected value or null in below code.

```
async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
const user = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);

if (!user) {
  throw new UnauthorizedException();
}

return user;
```

after that
if the user is always null the problem is existing in process to get user.
you should keep into debug where actually not working as you expect.
ex: validateUser, findOneWithEmail or something...

and I think there must be habe something problem with process to get user.
let's keep trace this error. give me more updated info thanks.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your question, but that function is the default function of the local strategy from the docs. It calls the validateUser from the authService which you can see above and the validateUser calls the findOneWithEmail which you can also see above. If you can, please be more especific, so I can help you helping me :)